# Integrating RJSON with ember

Tags: ember.js

I trying to integrate emberjs with [RJSON](https://github.com/dogada/RJSON) but I can't find where ember is decoding JSON. My first step was to extend `Application Serializer`

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalize: function(type, hash, prop) {

        hash = RJSON.unpack(hash);

        return this._super(type, hash, prop)
      },
});
```

but it is not going to work. Ember is passing in the hash already encoded data for only 1 records. I need to pass to `RJSON.unpack` whole array of records just after parsing JSON by ember. I am using `Ember Data` with `RESTAdapter`. Where Can I find proper method to extend?

Comment: You need to work with the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extended `ajax` method in `DS.RESTAdapter`.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        var adapter = this;

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, hash);

          hash.success = function(json) {
            json = RJSON.unpack(json);
            Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
          };

          hash.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Ember.run(null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR));
          };

          Ember.$.ajax(hash);
        }, "DS: RestAdapter#ajax " + type + " to " + url);
      },
});
```

Now I have my json size reduced by 50%.